# browsers are showing different views chrome vs firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, drupal

am making changes to my home page, using Drupal.

I think css may be the problem.

on Firefox my code works, however when I preview this on Google chrome, it shows a different view.

any ideas on what the problem can be..

[image: different browsers]

I don't understand why it works on one and doesn't on the other...

code (as this is drupal) i have downloaded module view ticker)

```
  .liScroll-container .mask {
    position: relative;
  left: 10px;
 width: 570px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

}

link: http://mja.anytimeafter9.co.uk/   (at the bottom)

```
  .liScroll-container {
 width: 570px;
 height: 29px;
margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: please put the html and `css` here

Comment: jsfiddle would do better rather than posting html and css :)

Comment: problem is i used a module in drupal

Comment: If this occurs after making changes to the CSS, make sure one of the browsers is not caching old versions of the stylesheet. Clear the caches are try again.

Comment: I looked at it really quick. You have a `div` inside a `span`... This is typically a no-no. Anyways, If you remove the span and give the div a line-height of 29px it works in Chrome... I assume it would work in Firefox too.

Comment: @Randy this came already with the drupal module. i feel if i change this more errors will come

Comment: Looks fine in Firefox and Chrome for me (on PC)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this issue before, try either updating both and/or reduce the css that manipulates the positioning. Sometimes I have solved this by giving more leeway or:

```
float: none ;margin: 0 auto;
```

or

```
float:left !important; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important;
```

adjust to your needs